# Adding 6 hours in R dataframe using an UDF

Tags: r, dataframe, function, lubridate

I have the below dataframe:

For Country = Hong Kong or Macau, I need to add 6 hours.

Input

| number | indate | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-05-05 7:41:28.277 | Hong Kong |
| 2 | 2020-05-05 17:41:28.277 | China |
| 3 | 2020-05-05 19:41:28.277 | Macau |
| 4 | 2020-05-05 17:41:28.277 | China |
| 5 | 2020-05-05 17:41:28.277 | USA |
| 6 | 2020-05-05 22:41:28.277 | Hong Kong |

Desired output:

| number | indate | country | indate1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-05-05 7:41:28.277 | Hong Kong | 2020-05-05 13:41:28.277 |
| 2 | 2020-05-15 17:41:28.277 | China | 2020-05-15 17:41:28.277 |
| 3 | 2020-05-12 19:41:28.277 | Macau | 2020-05-13 01:41:28.277 |
| 4 | 2020-05-25 17:41:28.277 | China | 2020-05-25 17:41:28.277 |
| 5 | 2020-05-05 17:41:28.277 | USA | 2020-05-05 17:41:28.277 |
| 6 | 2020-05-13 22:41:28.277 | Hong Kong | 2020-05-14 04:41:28.277 |

Below is the code I have written:

```
library(lubridate)

hour_addition = function(dataf) {
        country = dataf[3]
        date= dataf[2]
        if (country == 'Hong Kong' | country = 'Macau'){
        date=as_datetime(date)
        date1 = date+dhours(6)
        date1 = as.character(date1)
        } else {
                date1 = date
        }
            return (date1)
        }
        
    new_date = apply(df,1,hour_addition)    
    df$indate1=new_date
```

I am not getting the desired results, Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Please provide your data in a reproducible format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Don't use apply. It will mangle your dataframe. instead just work with the indate column. `Input$Indate1 <- Input$indate+dhours(6)`

Comment: @IRTFM the condition is if the country is equal to Hong Kong and Macau then only add 6 hour, rest all cases use the existing indate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it with UDF? It is much easier with dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
  number = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
  ,indate = c('2020-05-05 17:41','2020-05-05 17:41','2020-05-05 17:41','2020-05-05 17:41','2020-05-05 17:41','2020-05-05 17:41')
  ,country = c("Hong Kong","China","Macau","China","USA","Hong Kong")
)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(indate = ymd_hm(indate)
                ,indate1 = if_else(country %in% c('Hong Kong','Macau'), indate + hours(6), indate) )
```

Comment: the condition is if the country is equal to Hong Kong and Macau then only add 6 hour, rest all cases use the existing indate.

Comment: "If_else" is the function you are looking for. I've just updated my solution.

Comment: G, I have asked a continuation question can u please look into it.